# C# XML getting the Node & Value of the elements that come under a specific parent

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML as below, I couldn't have multiple data files to be given in app.config and get it moved to the bin/Debug folder during the build.  Hence I'm trying to have the test data in one XML file itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<AppTestData>
    <Contact>
        <Name>Abe</Name>
        <Age>33</Age>
        <City>York</City>
        ...
    </Contact>
    <Agent>
        <Code>A103S</Code>
        <Region>North</North>
        <Resp>Service</Resp>
        ....
    </Agent>
    <Product>
        <Cat>Electronics</Cat>
        ...
    </Product> 
</AppTestData>
```

My code will give whether its a Contact / Agent / Product ... and I need the elements below that to be a Dictionary.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(xmlName));    
Dictionary<string, string> appData = ParseTestDataXML.GetRecordData(<file_path>), "Contact");

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Contact").Where(p => !p.HasElements))
        {
            int keyInt = 0;
            string keyName = element.Name.LocalName;

            while (keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(keyName))
            {
                keyName = $"{element.Name.LocalName}_{keyInt++}";
            }

            keyValuePairs.Add(keyName, element.Value);
        }
```

But it adds every other element node and value from other parents like Agent.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, here is the code

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            XElement root = XElement.Load(filePath);
            IEnumerable<XElement> xElements =
                from element in root.Elements("Contact") select element;
            foreach (XElement el in xElements.Descendants().Where(p => !p.HasElements))
            {
                int keyInt = 0;
                string keyName = el.Name.LocalName;

                while (keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(keyName))
                {
                    keyName = $"{el.Name.LocalName}_{keyInt++}";
                }
                keyValuePairs.Add(keyName, el.Value);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);    
            //using a list
            Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> appData1 = doc.Root.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            //not using a list
            Dictionary<string, XElement> appData2 = doc.Root.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
     }
}
```